# How to write a query that get the sum of quantity of multiple rows from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a query that bring me the sales for today. I am using 4 tables in the database.

- First table called drugs that contain drugs names
- Second called Output it contains the sale id and the date
- third table called outputdetails that contains the drugs that sold in specific sale.
- fourth table called inputdetails that contain drugs entered to the store and their expiry dates

It may be multiple rows for one drug each expiry date is different, I want to get the sum of quantity for each drug of that are sold today.

here the query I am using but its giving me wrong numbers:

```
select DrugID,
       Drugs.Name,
       sum(InputDetails.Quantity) as 'Quantity' 
from InputDetails 
inner join Drugs on Drugs.ID = InputDetails.DrugID 
cross join Output
inner join OutputDetails on OutputDetails.OutputID = Output.ID
group by DrugID, Name;
```

Comment: Can we see sample data please to work on it

Comment: Unless your structure is somewhat strange, or your sale price is tied to the incoming drug shipments, I can not see why you are summing the `InputDetails.Quantity` instead of the `OutputDetails.Quantity`. When you describe OutputDetails as "the drugs that sold in specific sale", that should be your target. InputDetails would be resupply, which may or may not equal the sold amount (example: Vicodin is supplied in bottles of 30 or more pills. An Rx from a dentist frequently will be for 7, 14, or 21 pills. You would have to order another 30, but would have only sold a smaller amount.)

Comment: Also, you're mixing implicit-join syntax with explicit joins, which in your statement is presenting as a cross-join, which is almost certainly **not** what you want.  For clarity, always use explicit joins.  You probably want to join on a `DrugId` or something, but what the available criteria is is unclear; this was probably the primary driver for the duplication.

Comment: Laughing Vergil  thank u for the reply.... I am using inputdetails.Quantity because i want to view the remaining stock quantity of that drug...the quantity belonging to Outputdetails is the quantity of drugs sold in a specific sale.

Comment: Please learn how to "accept" and/or "upvote" answers to your questions.  Don't just ignore them once you get your solution. By "accepting" an answer  you inform everyone that you have found your solution and by upvoting you indicate which answers were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sales in a day is derived from tables 2 and 3 in your list

Output it contains the sale id and the date

outputdetails contains the drugs that sold in specific sale

But you have not identified sufficient columns in those tables to enable a full query to be built.

```
Select ...
From Output
inner join OutputDetails on OutputDetails.OutputID = Output.ID
Group by ...
```

You could also include the first table "drugs" in the  query but again we dont know enough yet.

---

Subsequent to your first comment below, if you do need to combine sales and stock information into a single result you need to aggregate sales and stock separately then join those to common information found in the drugs table. **There isn't enough details about the tables in your question** so the following is provided as a guide only. There has to be some way to explicitly join drugs to sales data (i.e. it cannot be a CROSS JOIN between drugs and output).

```
SELECT
      Drugs.ID
    , Drugs.Name
    , r.Stock
    , s.sales
FROM Drugs
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            DrugID
          , SUM(InputDetails.Quantity) AS 'Stock'
      FROM InputDetails
      GROUP BY
            DrugID
      ) r ON Drugs.ID = r.DrugID
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            output.DrugID
          , SUM(OutputDetails.Quantity) AS 'Sales'
      FROM Output
      INNER JOIN OutputDetails ON OutputDetails.OutputID = Output.ID
      GROUP BY
            output.DrugID
      ) o ON Drugs.ID = o.DrugID
```

Comment: thank you for your reply... this query you provide me is good for bringing sales in a day only, which is not enough for me... i want also to bring each drug remaining quantity in stock which is in table inputdetails. thank you again :)

Comment: `want also to bring each drug remaining quantity in stock`  Pity that wasn't stated in the question.

Comment: `I want to write a query that bring me the sales for today. ` *(That is what you stated)*

Comment: thank you very much...sorry for not providing info about the tables
here it is:
Drugs (ID,Name,Price)
InputDetails(InputID,DrugID,Expiry,QuantityStock)
Output(ID,Date,Total)
OutputDetails(OutputID,DrugID,Price,Quantity)

Comment: Used_By_Already really you helped me so much,,,its the query that i was trying to write for weeks ago>thank you very much 
I am very grateful to you